# How To Create dynamic div gor count value in php

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I am getting dynamic div from the count .. in seperate box but i want that i ve fixed 6 small div inside the container.and if i get the count value 10 then  it means auto pre added the div according to the dynamic value .. my code is given below.

```
<?php 

   echo '<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: white;height: auto;padding: 0px;border: px solid red;">';
   echo '<div class="col-md-2" style="font-weight: bold;floa:left;font-size:60px;text-align: center;border:px solid red;">';

   }
  echo '<div>';
?>
```

But If i get the 100 as count it look like:

0 1 0 0 but i want to fix 6 divs starting with the prefix 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `array_pad` function to pad the array with `0` to the desired length. Try the code below.

```
<?php 
$count=10;
 $array = array_pad(str_split($count), -5, 0);
//print_r($array);exit;
   echo '<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: white;height: auto;padding: 0px;border: px solid red;">';
   echo '<div class="col-md-2" style="font-weight: bold;floa:left;font-size:60px;text-align: center;border:px solid red;">';
  echo '<div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid green;">0</div>'; 
    echo '</div>';
   foreach($array as $value){
   echo '<div class="col-md-2" style="font-weight: bold;floa:left;font-size:60px;text-align: center;border:px solid red;">';
 echo '<div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid green;">'. $value.'</div>';
   echo '</div>';
   }
  echo '<div>';
?>
```